# Exception from MVC Controller constructor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, webforms

Recreates the Controller.

```
[HandleError]
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public HomeController()
    {
        throw new Exception("test");
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

This messes up my Exception handling logic, cause the first time my Exception occurs in the ImportedDocumentController, I clean up the uploaded file; 
Second time the Constructor doesn't throw the necessary Exception, cause there is no file.
Also the user does not get report about the original Exception in the uploaded data.

Answer (score 0):

Researching the issue, I found out, that its bad practice to throw Exception in constructor.